# Color picker for theme colors (Word)

Tags: vba, colors, ms-word, themes

The user of my Word application has to be able to select a color. I currently use the color picker dialog in this way:

```
Private Type CHOOSECOLOR
  lStructSize As LongLong
  hwndOwner As LongPtr
  hInstance As LongPtr
  rgbResult As LongLong
  lpCustColors As LongPtr
  flags As LongLong
  lCustData As LongLong
  lpfnHook As LongLong
  lpTemplateName As String
End Type

Private Declare PtrSafe Function MyChooseColor _
    Lib "comdlg32.dll" Alias "ChooseColorW" _
    (ByRef pChoosecolor As CHOOSECOLOR) As Boolean

Public Function GetColor(ByRef col As LongLong) As _
    Boolean

   Static CS As CHOOSECOLOR
   Static CustColor(15) As LongLong
   
   CS.lStructSize = Len(CS)
   CS.hwndOwner = 0
   CS.flags = &H1 Or &H2
   CS.lpCustColors = VarPtr(CustColor(0))
   CS.rgbResult = col
   CS.hInstance = 0
   GetColor = MyChooseColor(CS)
   If GetColor = False Then Exit Function '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
   
   GetColor = True
   col = CS.rgbResult
   End Function
```

However, I would like to offer a **panel of the currently active theme colors** to select from, to keep formatting consistency with the rest of the document.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there isn't a way of getting a built-in color picker dialog to display theme colors, so you'll need to create your own.

You can get to the colors using code like:

```
Document.DocumentTheme.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeAccent1).RGB
```

You need to be aware that when you apply the color to whatever object you are targeting you have to apply the theme color not its RGB value. Be prepared for the odd gotcha: not all objects have the required properties to be able to use theme colors.